# Simple Future chaining that have different value types using Combine

Tags: ios, swift, future, combine

The logic that I want to apply is:

If we have already imported the users we just fetch them otherwise import first the users and then fetch them. Here is my attempt :

```
import Combine

struct User {
    let name: String
}

var didAlreadyImportUsers = false

// Import the users and return true of false 
var importUsers: Future<Bool, Never> {
    Future { promise in
        promise(.success(true))
    }
}

var fetchUsers: Future<[User], Error> {
    Future { promise in
        promise(.success([User(name: "John"), User(name: "Jack")]))
    }
}

var users: Future<[User], Error> {
    if didAlreadyImportUsers {
        return fetchUsers
    } else {
        return importUsers.setFailureType(to: Error.self)
            .combineLatest(fetchUsers)
            .map { $0.1 }
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type
'Publishers.Map<Publishers.CombineLatest<Publishers.SetFailureType<Future<Bool, Never>, Error>, Future<[User], Error>>, [User]>' 
to return type 'Future<[User], Error>'
```

Any idea how to get the result of chaining as Future<[User], Error> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close! Just erase the type:

```
var users: AnyPublisher<[User], Error> {
    if didAlreadyImportUsers {
        return fetchUsers.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } else {
        return importUsers.setFailureType(to: Error.self)
            .combineLatest(fetchUsers)
            .map { $0.1 }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

You might say: Wait, that's not what I said to do; I want to return it as a Future. Well, *don't* want that! It *isn't* a Future; it's some horrible Future-plus-CombineLastest-plus-Map thingy. You don't want to know what it is. All you want to know is its output type and its failure type.

The whole point here is that one publisher is as good as another; they can be used interchangeably, *provided their types match*. That is why AnyPublisher is provided: it's so you can do exactly that. Basically, AnyPublisher is how you cast between publisher types: you just cast everything to AnyPublisher.

Comment: See my discussion of AnyPublisher [here](http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html) and [here](http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorswrappers.html), and my tips for developing successful Combine code [here](http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/tricksandtips.html).

Comment: That's exactly the answer that I was looking for. Thanks for sharing the links.